# Faster sockets in Python

Tags: python, performance, sockets, python-3.x

I have a client written in Python for a server, which functions through LAN. Some part of the algorithm uses socket reading intensively and it is executing about 3-6 times slower, than [almost the same one](http://pastie.org/3962231) written in C++. What solutions exist for making Python socket reading faster?

I have some simple buffering implemented, and my class for working with sockets looks like this:

```
import socket
import struct

class Sock():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.recv_buf = b''
        self.send_buf = b''

    def connect(self):
        self.s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 6666))

    def close(self):
        self.s.close()

    def recv(self, lngth):
        while len(self.recv_buf) < lngth:
                self.recv_buf += self.s.recv(lngth - len(self.recv_buf))

        res = self.recv_buf[-lngth:]
        self.recv_buf = self.recv_buf[:-lngth]
        return res

    def next_int(self):
        return struct.unpack("i", self.recv(4))[0]

    def next_float(self):
        return struct.unpack("f", self.recv(4))[0]

    def write_int(self, i):
        self.send_buf += struct.pack('i', i)

    def write_float(self, f):
        self.send_buf += struct.pack('f', f)

    def flush(self):
        self.s.sendall(self.send_buf)
        self.send_buf = b''
```

P.S.: profiling also shows that the majority of time is spent reading sockets.

**Edit:** Because data is received in blocks with known size, I can read the whole block at once.  So I've changed my code to this:

```
class Sock():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.send_buf = b''

    def connect(self):
        self.s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 6666))

    def close(self):
        self.s.close()

    def recv_prepare(self, cnt):
        self.recv_buf = bytearray()
        while len(self.recv_buf) < cnt:
            self.recv_buf.extend(self.s.recv(cnt - len(self.recv_buf)))

        self.recv_buf_i = 0

    def skip_read(self, cnt):
        self.recv_buf_i += cnt

    def next_int(self):
        self.recv_buf_i += 4
        return struct.unpack("i", self.recv_buf[self.recv_buf_i - 4:self.recv_buf_i])[0]

    def next_float(self):
        self.recv_buf_i += 4
        return struct.unpack("f", self.recv_buf[self.recv_buf_i - 4:self.recv_buf_i])[0]

    def write_int(self, i):
        self.send_buf += struct.pack('i', i)

    def write_float(self, f):
        self.send_buf += struct.pack('f', f)

    def flush(self):
        self.s.sendall(self.send_buf)
        self.send_buf = b''
```

`recv`'ing from socket looks optimal in this code. But now `next_int` and `next_float` became the second bottleneck, they take about 1 msec (3000 CPU cycles) per call just to unpack. Is it possible to make them faster, like in C++?

Comment: When you say reading sockets takes the most time when profiling, do you mean `self.s.recv` or `Sock.recv`?

Comment: Hm, I honestly haven't noticed before you wrote. `Sock.recv` takes 18 secs and `self.s.recv` takes 13 secs in profiled example (not cumulative).

Comment: You do a bit of byte copying. Maybe try using `bytearray()`, `socket.recv_into`, and `struct.pack_into` to squeeze some cycles?

Comment: 13 seconds?! Surely you miliseconds, right?

Comment: Another micro-optimization: `self.recv_buf` is only referenced in `recv` so you can make it local.  You don't need to save it between calls because your call to `self.s.recv` will only read the maximum data requested, so their shouldn't be data left over to save for later.

Comment: @kichik, no, seconds. I mean all calls, not one only (one call shows as 0.000 in profiling).

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, the only reason because I've done it this way is that I am not sure there will not be any data left.

Comment: It would be nice to see the similar c++ version.  Also, my impression is that you are reading in really small chunks and that sounds sub-optimal.  Additionally, operations that append to string or pop from the beginning of a string are really inefficient in python because of immutable strings cause creation of new strings each time.

Comment: @chrsanya:  The [docs claim](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) that you will not receive more data than you ask for:  "The maximum amount of data to be received at once is specified by bufsize."

Comment: I would say that buffering isn't the main issue. And if I remove all the buffering and replace `self.recv(4)` with `self.s.recv(4)`, those 18 seconds are still taken by reading from sockets.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, http://pastie.org/3962231 - corresponding C++ code. I'm not great at C++, but it seems to be very similar.

Comment: @chersanya: I know next to nothing about sockets, but the docs seem to contain an assumption that normal usage reads in much larger chunks:  "**Note**:
For best match with hardware and network realities, the value of bufsize should be a relatively small power of 2, for example, 4096."  If a socket needs a separate communication over the network for each chunk it reads, then I could see time adding up quickly.  I think that if you read in bigger chunks, though, your method of buffering would become the bottleneck.

Comment: I've changed the code to this: http://pastie.org/3965286 (data is received in blocks with known size, so I can read the whole block at once). `recv`'ing from socket looks optimal in this code. But now `next_int` and `next_float` became the second bottleneck, they take about 1 msec (3000 CPU cycles) per call just to unpack. Is it possible to make them faster, like in C++?

Comment: Check what in next_int takes time. Is it the slicing of the buffer or the unpacking? I'd guess the slicing of the buffer. I don't know why it's that slow, though, it should't be I think. But the unpacking is trivial, so it kinda has to be. If it is, a bytearray() might be worth a try instead of a byte string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your latest bottleneck is in `next_int` and `next_float` because you create intermediate strings from the `bytearray` and because you only unpack one value at a time.

The `struct` module has an `unpack_from` that takes a buffer and an offset.  This is more efficient because there is no need to create an intermediate string from your `bytearray`:

```
def next_int(self):
    self.recv_buf_i += 4
    return struct.unpack_from("i", self.recv_buf, self.recv_buf_i-4)[0]
```

Additionally, `struct` module can unpack more than one value at a time.  Currently, you call from Python to C (via the module) for each value.  You would be better served by calling it fewer times and letting it do more work on each call:

```
def next_chunk(self, fmt): # fmt can be a group such as "iifff" 
    sz = struct.calcsize(fmt) 
    self.recv_buf_i += sz
    return struct.unpack_from(fmt, self.recv_buf, self.recv_buf_i-sz)
```

If you know that `fmt` will always be 4 byte integers and floats you can replace `struct.calcsize(fmt)` with `4 * len(fmt)`.

Finally, as a matter of preference I think this reads more cleanly:

```
def next_chunk(self, fmt): 
    sz = struct.calcsize(fmt) 
    chunk = struct.unpack_from(fmt, self.recv_buf, self.recv_buf_i)
    self.recv_buf_i += sz
    return chunk
```