# How to read EFFICIENTLY from a socket

Tags: python, sockets, processing-efficiency

I need to read from a socket several times. Since I need to respond back within 2 seconds, the reading should be efficient, also when I need to read a line with more than `12,000` integers (the computation done with those integers does not take long, i.e. `0.015s`)

I have the following approach:

```
import socket

host = "SOMEHOST"
port = SOMEPORT

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((host, port))

def read_from_socket(client):
    response = ''
    char = ''
    while not '\n' in char:
        char = client.recv(1)
        response += char

    return response

for SOMEWHILE:
    line = read_from_socket(client)
    # do some stuff with line
    client.send(SOMEANSWER)
```

Can this be done more efficiently, such that it does not take longer than those 2 seconds to respond?

EDIT:
The input looks the like the following:

```
Case #SOME_NUMBER:
T N
N numbers
```

I have modified the code according to the comments like this:

```
def read_from_socket(client, size=1):
    if size > 1:
        return client.recv(size*4)
    else:
        response = ''
        char = ''

        while not '\n' in char:
            char = client.recv(size)
            response += char

        return response

for i in SOME_RANGE:

    case = read_from_socket(client)
    print case
    T, N = read_from_socket(client).split(' ')
    numbers = read_from_socket(client, int(N)).split(' ')   
    numbers = filter(None, numbers)
    numbers = [int(number) for number in numbers]

    answer = # DO SOME STUFF WITH numbers

    print "{}".format(answer)
```

Hereby I get the following output:

```
Case #1:

4
Case #2:

1
Case #3:

3
Case #4:

6
Case #5:

5
Case #6:

6
17 14 5 13 6 1 18 15 3 7 3 4 2 15 3 11 13 13 19 17 15 11 4 6 13 16 20 1 9 13 12 5 19 8 10 16 1 7 2 3 14 5 7 7 19 1 10 4 13 20 12 20 10 15 5 14 11 17 14 11 1 17 15 11 5 16 7 5 3 8 19 8 4 5 6 3 18 15 18 10 6 9 9 16 4 6 9 6 14 15 16 6 11 2 17 7 18 3 3 12 2 2 11 6 18 16 20 15 3 17 17 8 5 5 15 20 2 16 17 7 10 4 13 12 6 9 19 15 3 1 18 16 14 8 1 12 15 12 18 9 8 14 9 5 11 3 4 12 18 13 11 19 16 3 11 13 3 1 19 17 13 16 12 7 15 5 10 2 16 19 10 16 13 18 20 3 13 15 6 10 7 8 1 3 10 3 7 4 3 6 20 15 1 12 13 8 8 14 9 3 13 10 10 5 8 9 19 12 4 16 13 10 4 13 4 5 15 11 9 17 16 20 4 8 3 8 7 10 2 15 5 14 17 14 18 16 15 8

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numbers.py", line 143, in <module>
    numbers = read_from_socket(client, int(N)).split(' ')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#7:\n'
```

In the last case, `N = 2400`. As far as I know, `N` could be bigger than 12,000

Comment: Why are you reading 1 byte at a time? Try `client.recv(4096)` or higher

Comment: @JRG I have tried this, the problem there was that I have read multiple lines. The server always sends 3 lines, but I only need the last one.

Comment: What you are actually doing is returning only the first one, is that what you want?

Comment: Presumably this is python2, since you are comparing strings and client.recv?

Comment: Then read the full text and split the result into an array and process only the last one in up coming logic. 
Maybe this is helpful for [reading/socket-performcance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742639/faster-sockets-in-python)